# Laravel Blade Foreach

Tags: laravel, if-statement, foreach, laravel-blade

I am developing for an application. I have an array of folder_data then I want that for **same file_names will be displayed only once**. I would appreciate your help.

This is my code:

```
@foreach($files['folders'] as $file)
                <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="{{$file['file_id']}}"></td>
                  <td>
                    <a href={{url("/home/".$file['file_name'])}}>
                      {{ $file['file_name'] }}
                    </a>
                  </td>
                  <td class="center">{{ $file['file_type'] }}</td>
                </tr>
              @endforeach
```

**UPDATE**:

$files['folders'] contains

- file_name, file_size, file_location,  file_type

I want it to display unique file_names. Pls help

Comment: You tell us what you want to do but I dont see where you are stuck and what you need help with.

Comment: im stuck at i want my file_names to not display duplicates

Comment: can you post an example structure of your array? just do a `<pre>{{print_r($files)}}</pre>` **make sure to put it as an update to your question**

Comment: do the pre and also your if statement is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Try like this

> array_unique — Removes duplicate values from an array

[PHP DOC](http://array_unique%20%E2%80%94%20Removes%20duplicate%20values%20from%20an%20array)

```
    @foreach(array_unique($files['folders'],SORT_REGULAR)  as $file)
                <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="{{$file['file_id']}}"></td>
                  <td>
                    <a href={{url("/home/".$file['file_name'])}}>
                      {{ $file['file_name'] }}
                    </a>
                  </td>
                  <td class="center">{{ $file['file_type'] }}</td>
                </tr>
    @endforeach
```

Comment: yes i found that too. but how can i put that in the loop? in laravel blade @tech-sira

Comment: `@foreach(array_unique($files['folders']) as $file)` try this and tell me what happen :)

Comment: all Laravel Blade is is a template compiler. All those `{{}}` allow you to do php functions. so like tech-sira does you just put it in the foreach loop and it should work. Now the real question is... are you trying to prevent duplicates on the server??? If so that is a different problem.

Comment: no. the concept goes like this. if the user creates a folder it will create to 3 drives. i want that in the user dashboard, it will display the file_name once but internally is in 3 drives. @Cayce K

Comment: @KristineJoanneTigue updated the answer according to your array structure.. `foreach(array_unique($files['folders'],SORT_REGULAR)  as $file)`

Comment: can you post `var_dump($files['folders']);` output ?